# Intellij ignores .gitignore file - gray icon, no sign, slash circle, slash symbol

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gitignore

For some reason Intellij ignores my .gitignore file. The .idea folder and so on are tracked. Does anyone have any idea why this is the case? What is the meaning of the gray icon in the bottom right corner?

[image: .gitignore with no sign]

Comment: `.gitignore` will only ignore new files not already tracked files. IntelliJ will start ignoreing files after `.gitignore` is added to git.

Comment: The thing is that in VSCode gitignore is recognized.

Answer (score 2):

**Not Ignoring**
If you have these entries in your .gitignore it should work as long as they aren't versioned already in your repo:

```
.idea/
target/
```

**Gray Icon**
That gray cross icon is just the common icon used for .gitignore files on IntelliJ. My projects have it too.